# Calculate the duration of a state with a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I try to calculate how often a state is entered and how long it lasts. For example I have the three possible states 1,2 and 3, which state is active is logged in a pandas Dataframe:

```
test = pd.DataFrame([2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,2,2,1,1], index=pd.date_range('00:00', freq='1h', periods=14))
```

For example the state 1 is entered two times (at index 3 and 12), the first time it lasts three hours, the second time two hours (so on average 2.5). State 2 is entered 3 times, on average for 2.66 hours.

I know that I can mask data I'm not interested in, for example to analyize for state 1:

```
state1 = test.mask(test!=1)
```

but from there on I can't find a way to go on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope the comments give enough explanation - the key point is you can use a custom rolling window function and then cumsum to group the rows into "clumps" of the same state.

```
# set things up
freq = "1h"
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,2,2,1,1],
    index=pd.date_range('00:00', freq=freq, periods=14)
)

# add a column saying if a row belongs to the same state as the one before it
df["is_first"] = pd.rolling_apply(df, 2, lambda x: x[0] != x[1]).fillna(1)

# the cumulative sum - each "clump" gets its own integer id
df["value_group"] = df["is_first"].cumsum()

# get the rows corresponding to states beginning
start = df.groupby("value_group", as_index=False).nth(0)
# get the rows corresponding to states ending
end = df.groupby("value_group", as_index=False).nth(-1)

# put the timestamp indexes of the "first" and "last" state measurements into
# their own data frame
start_end = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "start": start.index,
        # add freq to get when the state ended
        "end": end.index + pd.Timedelta(freq),
        "value": start[0]
    }
)
# convert timedeltas to seconds (float)
start_end["duration"] = (
    (start_end["end"] - start_end["start"]).apply(float) / 1e9
)
# get average state length and counts
agg = start_end.groupby("value").agg(["mean", "count"])["duration"]
agg["mean"] = agg["mean"] / (60 * 60)
```

And the output:

```
           mean  count
value                 
1      2.500000      2
2      2.666667      3
3      1.000000      1
```

Comment: I understand the basic idea how you solve the problem, but I'm uncommon to the groupby methods, and exactly these raise an TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list (both lines, the `start =` and `end =`)

Comment: I'm using Pandas 0.16.0. I think the behavior of groupby().nth is different in older versions. Try .nth(0) instead of .nth([0]). (Will update answer to reflect this)

Comment: Okay, this was the reason, your code works for me if I use `nth(0)`, I am still on Pandas 0.13.1... . next thing that didn't work is `pd.Timedelta`, that's not existent in my version. But never mind, the way I clear from this point, I'll figure the rest out on my own. Thanks a lot.